# How can i find the length of a nested array objectlist in react?

Tags: reactjs

This is my data:

```
const Datasitems = [
  {
    index: 1,
    img1: img1,
    productname: "something",
    images: [
      { id: 1, im: img1 },
      { id: 2, im: img1a },
      { id: 3, im: img1b }
    ]
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    img1: img2,
    productname: "something",
    images: [
      { id: 1, im: img1 },
      { id: 2, im: img1a },
      { id: 3, im: img1b }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have a slider which is reactstrap carousel, code goes like this

```
const Example = (props) => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

    const next = () => {
        if (animating) return;
        const nextIndex = activeIndex === Datasitems.images.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
        setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
      }
  
    const previous = () => {
      if (animating) return;
      const nextIndex = activeIndex === 0 ? Datasitems.images.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1;
      setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
    }
  
    const goToIndex = (newIndex) => {
      if (animating) return;
      setActiveIndex(newIndex);
    }
  
    const slides = Datasitems.map((item) => {
      return (
          
        <CarouselItem
          onExiting={() => setAnimating(true)}
          onExited={() => setAnimating(false)}
          key={item.src}
        >{item.imageses.map((c)=>{
            return(<img src={c.src} alt={item.altText} />)
        })}
          
          <CarouselCaption captionText={item.productname} captionHeader={item.price} />
        </CarouselItem>
      );
    });
  
    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={activeIndex}
        next={next}
        previous={previous}
      >
        {slides}
        <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={previous} />
        <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={next} />
      </Carousel>
    );
  }
```

Here in next and previous functions, I can't find the length of an array: images
and display the carousel

Please share your thoughts and solutions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean with "I can't find the length of an array"? Where is your DatasItems defined?

Comment: `Datasitems` is an array, which element of `Datasitems` are you trying to get the `images` array length of? Seems you should track two indices, one for which `Datasitems` element is active, and the other for which `Datasitems.images` is active.

Answer (score 0):

Datasitems is an array.

So you should use index to get the first object item.

```
Datasitems[0].images.length
```

In your case you are using activeIndex to find the object, am I right?
Then should be

```
Datasitems[activeIndex].images.length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parents.js

<Example ccc={Datasitems} />
```

```
export const Example = (props) => {
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
    const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

    const [inProps, setInProps] = useState(props.ccc);
    console.log(inProps[0].images.length)
```